# how to hide particular cells in collectionview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my project i got a **array** which i am loading on my **collectionview**

```
var dataSource = ["@", "@", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" , "9", "10", "@", "@"]
```

for the string "@" i want to hide that particular cell. so initially i was trying to do it using indexpath and then tried to check if my array position got value "@". But i am unable to hide it properly as some other cell would get changed on scroll

So this what i have done on my **cellForItemAt** :

```
if dataSource[indexPath.row] == "@" {

            cell.contentView.isHidden = true
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        }
```

Things to be considered its scrolling horizontally and this is my **sizeForItemAt** :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        return CGSize(width: (self.numberCollectionView?.bounds.size.width)!/5 - 3, height: (self.numberCollectionView?.bounds.size.width)!/5 - 3 )
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are reusing the cell, so you need to add else part also of that condition to set `isHidden` to `false` and default `borderColor`.

```
if dataSource[indexPath.row] == "@" {

    cell.contentView.isHidden = true
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
}
else {
    cell.contentView.isHidden = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor //Set Default color here
}
```

Also if you doesn't want to show the cell that why don't you remove that element from your array using `filter`.

```
dataSource = dataSource.filter { $0 != "@" }
```

And now just reload the `collectionView`.

Comment: @Fay007 Welcome mate :) Also check the edited answer of filter

Answer (score 5):

You can completely get rid of that cells only by filtering your dataSource array.

```
    var filtered = dataSource.filter { (item) -> Bool in
       item != "@"
    }
```

and use this filtered array instead of source.

Comment: actually i need those empty cells to fulfill my designs need